# Yammer disable/remove/delete registered applications

Tags: office365, yammer

I develop Yammer applications.

I want to disable/remove an app that I registered. I googled but still found no way to disable/remove an registered app.
https://www.yammer.com/client_applications

Any idea will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apps will be disabled if the Yammer account associated with them is suspended.

It is no longer possible for the support team to assist with requests to remove apps. If an app is no longer used or needed, you are best to ignore it. You can change the client's Redirect URI to a webpage with a custom message if you want to display something for users explaining that the application can no longer be authorized.

Comment: I have this problem as well (need to delete or at least rename an app that I started working on).  There seem to be many places you can open a ticket.  Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this can be done now from "New Yammer". These options don't seem to be available in "old" Yammer.

On your Yammer home page, click the Yammer settings icon

[image]

Click **Edit settings**

[image]

Click **MY APPLICATIONS**.

[image]

Next to the apps that you want to remove access from, click **Revoke Access**

[image]

Any query that used the app and token will now be broken. Here's an example from Power Query in Excel:
[image]

From https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-uninstall-app-in-yammer/3eb1df44-c070-4e2b-9b4b-ea64f83e98c3